# No se reconoce variable de entorno - Nodejs

Tags: nodejs, variables-de-configuración

He echo lo que hago en todo proyecto, instalo **dotenv** con `npm i dotenv`, creo mi archivo `.env` y lo llamo en el archivo que lo necesito, primero requiero el modulo con `require('dotenv').config`, e inicializo mi variable `const db = process.env.DB_CONNECTION`, sin embargo cuado trate de conectarme a la base de datos no se me conectaba, hice un `console.log(db)` y el log fue `undefined`. cual es el error?, no se por que pasa esto. He trabajado siempre con las variables de entorno y es la primera vez que me pasa esto.

**conexion.js (Archivo de conexion)**

```
require('dotenv').config
const mongoose = require('mongoose')
const db = process.env.DB_CONNECTION
console.log(db) // devuelve undefined
const client = mongoose.connect(db,{ useNewUrlParser: true, useUnifiedTopology: true}) 
//no se conecta por que la variable no tiene un string como valor
```

**Archivo .env**

```
DB_CONNECTION = miCadenaDeConexion
```

**Estructura de directorios**

```
proyecto
-db
 -conexion.js
-index.js
-node_modules
-package.json
-.env
```

**versiones**
version de node = 14.1.0
version de dotenv = 8.2.0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Veo un error donde requieres dotenv y llamas la configuración.

```
require('dotenv').config
```

.config es una función por lo tanto debe llevar parentesis.

```
require('dotenv').config();
```

Comment: Muchas gracias, me había olvidado, hice las cosas muy rápido y se me paso

Answer (score 2):

`.config` es una función por lo tanto debe llevar paréntesis `()`.

```js
require('dotenv').config();
```

Con esta configuración reconoce el archivo `.env` y las variables que se declaren en el.

Comment: jeje... sip, me habia olvidado de eso, muchas gracias!